# How to integrate $\sin(x)\, dt$, as $x$ a function of $t$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got $-\frac{\cos(x)}{x'} + c$, but doesn't feel right.
The full problem is $x''\, dt=\sin(x)\,dt$

then $x'=-\frac{\cos(x)}{x'} + c$

after multiplicate all for $x'$

$x'^2=-\cos(x) + c\cdot x'$
then I have a quadratic function to find the velocity=x'

$x'^2-c\cdot x'+\cos(x)=0$
Is it wrong to solve it that way?

Comment: Can you try using TeX? Do you mean that the question was $\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = \sin(x)$ ?

Comment: yes, that's the question, and I have to find the velocity, what is Tex?

Comment: How did you get the first line? Integrating both sides gives $x' + c = -\cos(x) + c_0$; is that not sufficient? (And TeX is what makes math print look pretty. It turns x^2 into $x^2$ by putting dollar signs around the math input.)